# cordovaで作成したアプリのバージョン情報を取得方法

Tags: cordova

cordovaを使用して作成したハイブリットアプリのバージョン情報を取得する方法があるでしょうか？

やりたいことは下記のようなことです。

◎「インストールされているアプリのバージョンをチェックし、ストアに誘導する」
http://qiita.com/jakais0041/items/0220685c6d3a724fd0d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のようなCordova pluginならありますが、要望にあってますか？
https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version

以下のようにしてJavascriptからアプリのバージョンを取得できます。

```
cordova.getAppVersion.getVersionNumber(function (version) {
    alert(version);
});
```